# Is there an ARM based ubuntu OS I can install on the Microsoft Surface RT?

Tags: windows, surface

Since the price of the Microsoft Surface has dropped significantly, I'm seriously considering getting one. The only problem - I hate Windows. I would really love to install Ubuntu on it - even if I have to run it from a flash drive. I just would like double assurance, and maybe some instruction on how I could do the install! Either way, I think you guy will be able to help me on this one. If I can't, then I'll probably just buy an iPad Mini (which wouldn't be AS cool...) Cheers! - Mike